# Group by project,user and month , and sume the hours

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This keeps a record of each time the worker has worked on that project, and there may be several records in a single day because he works on several things.
I have this collection "WORKSDAYS":

```
{
    "_id" : "00007cASDASDASDAS32423423",
    "workDate" : ISODate("2017-01-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"),
    "hours" : 6.0,
    "worker" : {
        "$ref" : "T_WORKERS",
        "$id" : "f3f849d1-8777-4066-bdc6-64625475bbff"
    },
    "project" : {
        "$ref" : "T_PROJECTS",
        "$id" : "03b80b87-dc3b-4dc3-88c4-2b3334758459"
    }
}
```

I need something similar to this for each project:

```
    {
    _id: { $ref: T_WORKERS, $id: id},
    january: 168,
    febrary: 120,
    ...
}
```

Or instead of January put 0 or 1, february = 02, etc.
I tried this that the workers gives me and the total hours of the project, but I would like the hours for each month:

```
    aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
                "project.$id": "03b80b87asdasdasdasd9"
              }
    },{
       $group: {
                "_id": "$worker",
                "hours":{"$sum":"$hours"}
        }
    }
])
```

I had also thought, in passing him the start and end date (example: January and December and to join them)

```
.aggregate([
    {$match: {
                "project.$id": "03b80b8asdasdasdasdasd7"
              }
    }, {
        $group: {
                "_id": "$worker",
                "month": { 
                        "$sum": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { "$gt": [
                                    { "$subtract": [ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") ] },
                                    new Date().valueOf() - ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 )
                                ]},
                                "$hours",
                                0
                            ]
                        }
                    }
            }
        }])
```